# Equation solving using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, iteration

I have a function of `t`, which is like this:
`I(t) = a*t^2 + b*t + c`, and `a,b,c` is given.
and solve the following function using MATLAB:

`Ttn = R*I(tn)^2 + Tt(n-1) * I(tn) - Tt(n-1)^4` , `Ttn` means `T` at time `tn`, `Tt(n-1)` means `T` at time `t(n-1)`, `R` is given and time `t` is from 0 to 10s.

I would really appreciate it, if somebody can help me with that.

Comment: T at time t0 is also given

Comment: Don't add additional information in the comments, use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42972678/edit) button for this. What did you try so far?

Comment: Sorry dude, I tried to understand but confused.

Comment: I'll suggest taking a look at [symbolic functions](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html)